# Bash: remove semicolons from a line in a CSV-file

Tags: bash

I've a CSV-file with a few hundred lines and a lot (not all) of these lines contains data (Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1)  which I want to extract.
i.e. ***;;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;***

I want to delete the semicolons which are in front of Klas/Lesgroep but the number of semicolons is variable. How can I delete these semicolons in Bash ?

I'm not a native speaking Englishman so I hope it's clear to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove any nonempty run of `;` chars. that come directly before literal `Klas/Lesgroep`:

With GNU or BSD/macOS `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's|;+(Klas/Lesgroep)|\1|' <<< ";;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;"
Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;
```

- The `s` function performs string substitution (replacement):

  - The 1st argument is a regex (regular expression) that specifies what part of the line to match,
  - and the 2nd arguments specifies what to replace the matching part with.
  - Note how I've chosen `|` as the regex/argument delimiter instead of the customary `/`, because that allows *unescaped* use of `/` chars. *inside* the regex.
- `;+` matches one or more directly adjacent `;` chars.
- `(Klas/Lesgroep)` matches literal `Klas/Lesgroep` and by enclosing it in `(...)` - making it a *capture group* - the match is remembered and can be referenced as `\1` - the 1st capture group in the regex - in the *replacement* argument to `s`.

The net effect is that all `;` chars. directly preceding `Klas/Lesgroep` are *removed*.

---

POSIX-compliant form:

```
$ sed 's|;\{1,\}\(Klas/Lesgroep\)|\1|' <<< ";;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;"
Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;
```

POSIX requires the less powerful and antiquated [BRE syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), where duplication symbol `+` must be emulated as `\{1,\}`, and, generally, metacharacters `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` must be `\`-escaped.

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can search for lines starting with at least one semi-colon followed by `Klas/Lesgroep` and, if found, substitute leading `;` with nothing:

```
$ sed '/;;*Klas\/Lesgroep/s/^;*//g' <<< ";;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;"
Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all ";" from a file , we can use sed command . sed is used for modifying the files.

```
$ sed 's/find/replace/g' file
```

The substitute flag /g (global replacement) specifies the sed command to replace all the occurrences of the string in the line.

So to remove ";" just find and replace it with nothing.

```
sed 's/;//g' file.csv
```

Comment: Maybe I misread but the answers are not working and I've also tried 
sed 's|;\{1,\}\(Klas/Lesgroep\)|\1|' <<< ";;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;"
"Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;" textfile.txt 
I noticed that it outputs to the screen but maybe not to the file?

Comment: I give it another try with sed 's|;\{1,\}(Klas/Lesgroep)|\1|' <<< ";;;;;;Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;" "Klas/Lesgroep:;;T2B1;;;;;;;;;;" oldfile.txt newfile.txt and now it works like a charm. Thank you all !